# JQuery - Unable to find element ID after child element is removed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to remove a the 'row' div with query after the 'del4' button is selected, and then rename all the inputs within the remaining row div(s). To rename the inputs in the remaining row div(s), I want to loop through the children of the 'sortable' div.

I can find the sortable div prior to removing the row div, but can't find the sortable div after removing the row.

HTML:

```
<div class="sortable ui-sortable" id="AutostationCLEAR">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><div class="col-md-6"><p><strong><input type="hidden" name="state_id0" value="0">1.</strong></p></div><div class="col-md-6"><p class="text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></p></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="stateName0" placeholder="State"></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="occupied0" value="1"></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="clear0" value="1"></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><p><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm del4" id="0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"><div class="col-md-6"><p><strong><input type="hidden" name="state_id1" value="">2.</strong></p></div><div class="col-md-6"><p class="text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></p></div></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="stateName1" placeholder="State"></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="occupiedundefined" value="1"></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="clear1" value="1"></p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><p><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm del4" id="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.del4',function(){
    alert($(this).closest(\".sortable\").attr('id')); \\shows sortable div id as expected
    $(this).closest(\".row\").remove(); \\remove the row
    alert($(this).closest(\".sortable\").attr('id')); \\no longer shows sortable div id
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have removed the `row` containing the current element from the dom tree, the current element is no longer present in the dom tree, so it will not be able to find the `sortable` element.

So you need to get the reference to the closest `sortable` fore the row is removed

```
$(document).on('click', '.del4', function () {
    var $sortable = $(this).closest('.sortable');
    alert($sortable.attr('id')); //shows sortable div id as expected
    $(this).closest('.row').remove(); //remove the row
    //do further processing using $sortable here
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7MVrQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to cache the closest element initially as other experts suggested.

```
$(document).on('click','.del4',function(){
    var cache = $(this).closest('.sortable');
    $(this).closest(".row").remove(); 
    alert(cache.attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: even if you cache the `row` element reference, once it is removed it will not have an parent so again the closest reference will fail

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh.. ok.. can we traverse inside of that removed element..? I know you wont answer this, atleast link me to one such link..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you can traverse down, not up, looking for descendants, not (older) ascendants